# Как сделать, чтобы картинки выстраивались в 2 колонки?

Tags: css, css3, flexbox, адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

Делаю адаптив с flexbox. Необходимо, чтобы при медиа-запросе @media (max-width: 1200px) картинки выстраивались не в колонку, а в две колонки. Каким свойством CSS это можно сделать?

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.images {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .images {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="images row">
  <img src="https://clck.ru/FKpWo">
  <img src="https://clck.ru/FKpWo">
  <img src="https://clck.ru/FKpWo">
  <img src="https://clck.ru/FKpWo">
</div>
```

В представленном коде получается только одна колонка. Мне надо сделать 2 колонки, чтобы в каждой было по 2 картинки. Разделить дивами не вариант.

Comment: я не смогу корректно ответить, потому что сам не до конца соображаю во flex.
Но смысла flex - уместить в 1 строку и сделать адаптивно.
flex не панацея, и именно для Вашего случая я бы рекомендовал grid (т.е., не всё можно сверстать с помощью flex).

Comment: возможно пропробую grid, но интересно сделать через flexbox. Сделать две колонки надо по шаблону дизайнера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку Вы задаёте flex-direction: column, то всё содержимое и выстраивается в одну колонку. Лучше задайте обёртке свойство flex-wrap: wrap (тогда картинки будут переноситься на новую строку), а самим картинкам - max-width: 50% (тогда их всегда будет по две):

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.images {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .images {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="images row">
  <img src="https://clck.ru/FKpWo">
  <img src="https://clck.ru/FKpWo">
  <img src="https://clck.ru/FKpWo">
  <img src="https://clck.ru/FKpWo">
</div>
```